# Can't change gid with mount

Tags: linux, mount, uid

I'm mounting a MicroSD card using this command:

```bsh
mount -t vfat -o uid=1001,gid=1001 /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sd
```

After that, I issue a `mount` command and notice that `gid=100` in the listing.

I've tried using the `remount` option but the gid never changes.  Also, the `uid` doesn't show up in the list.  The output of mount is:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/sd type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,gid=100,fmask=0002,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro,user)
```

If I remount with `ro`, then that property changes.

I'm running on a BeagleBone AI with Debian.

Any thoughts?

Comment: (Arch-based system) I tried this with my EFI partition (mounted to `/mnt`) and got the same results: uid and gid options were ignored. According to the `mount` man page, this *should* work.

Comment: It works here. Is this using `mount` from the `util-linux` package or is it within `busybox`? If so, try running `/usr/bin/mount ...`. Secondly, run `strace` against it and make sure that it is making the syscall with the options as you have supplied them.

Comment: Are you sure that /media isn’t an automount directory for udisks2?